# When argument in method is allocated in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, callback, arguments

Can you let me know when method(function in a function)'s argument is allocated?
if the arguments in method(in a function)is allocated when they are declared, there's no value of `USERNAME.value` when it is declared.

but If I put Stored Name as a argument of greeting in function store(which is call back function used for event),null comes out even if I put my user name on in input box.
However, If I put `USERNAME.value`, it works properly.

This is my js code,

```js
const USERNAME = document.getElementById("username");
const Form = document.querySelector("form");
const HIDDEN = "hidden";
const h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
const KEY = "username";

function greeting(who) {
    h2.innerText = `Hello, ${who}`;
    h2.classList.remove(HIDDEN);
}

function store(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    localStorage.setItem(KEY, USERNAME.value);
    Form.classList.add(HIDDEN);
    greeting(StoredName);
}
const StoredName = localStorage.getItem(KEY);


if (StoredName == null) {
    Form.classList.remove(HIDDEN);
    Form.addEventListener("submit", store);

} else {
    greeting(StoredName);

}
```

and this is my html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 class="hidden"></h2>
    <form action="" class="hidden">
        <input type="text" name="" id="username">
        <input type="submit" value="">
    </form>
    <script src="practice.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The memory for the argument is allocated on the stack when the function is called.

Comment: The `value` property is in the object that `USERNAME` refers to. That memory exists independently of the function argument. So I'm not sure what you mean by "there's no value of USERNAME.value when it is declared."

Comment: I don't think you're asking the right question. It has nothing to do with memory allocation, your question seems to be when the argument expression is evaluated. And it's evaluated every time the function is called.

Comment: The problem is that you only assign `storedName` once when the page is loaded. You don't reassign it after saving a new value to local storage.

Comment: `storedName` is NOT an alias for the expression `localStorage.getItem(KEY)`. It gets assigned the result of that call when you assign it, not every time you use the variable.